# Redirect at root site

Tags: redirect

I have a publishing site in sharepoint 2010.

I want to make it possible for users to enter the URL:

http://www.examplesite.com/courses/

and get redirected to

http://www.examplesite.com/en-US/Courses.

The issue is that if I create a redirect page on the web root, it gets created with the URL:

http://www.examplesite.com/Pages/Redirect.aspx, and not
http://www.examplesite.com/Redirect.aspx

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do redirects is at the IIS level with the IIS Rewrite module.  You can download it here: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Basically you will create a rule for the /courses/ URL that rewrites it as /en-US/courses/.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Is it not possible to do it in the SharePoint 2010 UI?

Comment: You could create a blank site at /courses/.  That will result in /courses/default.aspx being created.   You could add redirect code to the default.aspx page (JavaScript or a meta refresh).